# Ioic With react

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-react

How can i generate build in ionic with react
I follow following step

- ionic cap add android
- ionic cap copy android
  -ionic cap run android
  This command create android folder but there is no any apk file please help me

Comment: The APK should create it using Android Studio, with the Android folder generated by the Build, It really happens to be more a question from Android Studio, than from Ionic.

Answer (score 0):

`ionic build`

`ionic cap add android`

`ionic cap open android` (to open the project in Android Studio)

For reference:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/your-first-app/6-deploying-mobile
https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/your-first-app/6-deploying-mobile#android

To generate an APK :
You can do a release build in Android Studio like a regular Android project. Follow the Android documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/run